# Using DateTimeField in Django with Oracle

Tags: python, sql, django, oracle, datetime

I have table in Oracle, which has field of DATE type. Also I have model in Django with DateTimeField. I want to save datetime in Oracle's DATE field, but Django ORM raises such exception:

`DatabaseError: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string`

I tried to use Django DateField, but it didn't save datetime, only date. How can I save datetime in Oracle using Django (I don't want to use DATETIME field in Oracle because of legacy problems).

My model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    filled_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='filled_date')
```

Comment: This is an error from Oracle's side. What date format are you using?

Comment: I use default value from django.timezone: django.timezone.now().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for problem. 
Oracle waits format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', but datetime.datetime.now() returns string like this: u'2013-10-18 05:50:44.332577'.
The solution:

```
model.filled_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
model.save()
```